# Oracle ASM disk group list

Tags: linux, lvm, oracle-database

We have [Oracle ASM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e18951/asmcon.htm) running under LVM and now I want to expand one of ASM disk group size, but I don't know which LVM filesystem is associated with specific ASM disk group. Is there a way to find out how many raw disk or `LVM` disk associated with ASM disk group?

> disk group
>
> An Oracle ASM disk group is a collection of disks that Oracle ASM manages as a unit. Within a disk group, Oracle ASM exposes a file system interface for Oracle Database files. The content of files that are stored in a disk group are evenly distributed, or striped, to eliminate hot spots and to provide uniform performance across the disks. Oracle ASM files may also be optionally mirrored within a disk group. The performance of disks in a disk group is comparable to the performance of raw devices.

#### EDIT #1

following are my disk group in ASM now `EXDATA` running out of space `99% used`. I have enough space in LVM so i am planing to expend LVM disk but i don't know which LVM volume i should expend because there are many LVM disk/filesystem showing in `lvdisplay` command.

```
[root@devserver ~]# /etc/init.d/oracleasm listdisks
EXDATA
EXLOG
STDATA
STLOG
PXDATA
PXLOG
OCR
XDDATA
XDLOG
```

Question: How to find which `LVM volume` associated with `EXDATA` (asm)? so i can run `lvextend` on LVM volume and increase the size of EXDATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind i got my answer myself

```
[root@devserver ~]# /sbin/blkid | grep oracleasm | grep EXDATA
/dev/mapper/asmdataVG-asmdata01LV: LABEL="EXDATA" TYPE="oracleasm"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31107/asmprepare.htm) you really shouldn't be running this on top of LVM.

> Raw logical volumes (LVM)—LVMs are supported in less complicated configurations where an LVM is mapped to a LUN, or an LVM uses disks or raw partitions. LVM configurations are not recommended by Oracle because they create a duplication of functionality. Oracle also does not recommended using LVMs for mirroring because ASM already provides mirroring.

Assuming you're using LVMs in a very basic way you should be able to determine what LVM Volume Group (VG) the ASM is using and from there walk down the hierarchy of VG -> LV -> PV.

Where:

- VG - Volume Group
- LV - Logical Volume
- PV - Physical Volume

#### Example

Here's my Volume Group (vg-grinchy):

```
$ sudo vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_grinchy   1   3   0 wz--n- 304.22g    0
```

I only have the one VG. Here are the Logical Volumes within it:

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV      VG         Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  lv_home vg_grinchy -wi-ao 248.53g                                      
  lv_root vg_grinchy -wi-ao  50.00g                                      
  lv_swap vg_grinchy -wi-ao   5.69g
```

There are 3. And finally here's the Physical Volume that these 3 volumes are sitting on:

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda6  vg_grinchy lvm2 a-   304.22g    0
```

So the underlying physical disk is `/dev/sda6`.